# Can't use ctrl key in the game

Tags: keyboard, games, mint

I'am using Linux Mint and really love it. But there is an annoying issue. When I press the **ctrl** key, mouse pointer is doing some animation and I can't use **ctrl** key in the game. When I hold **ctrl** key in the game, it get me out of the game. Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are welcome here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Mint forum.

Comment: I think You have "Show me where the mouse is" enabled. It is available in Ubuntu in Gnome Tweak Tools, and I had a problem with just a few days ago. It was enabled, and when I tried to let's say Select All in Firefox URL bar, it was loosing focus or loosing selection. Maybe this will be helpful to find out how to disable it in Mint
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=263535

Comment: Thanks man. It helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferences => Mouse & Touchpad => Mouse => General => Show position of pointer when the Control key is pressed.